# Looping through $_POST array values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, post

If I have this $_POST array:

```
session[1][0]=50&
session[1][1]=60&
session[2][0]=70&
session[3][0]=80
```

How can I use a for loop to get the value of the session and of the item? I thought this would work but it does not.

```
foreach ($_POST['session'] as $i => $value) {
    $session = $session[$i];
    $item = $value;

    $query->bindValue(':session', $session, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':item', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();

}
```

So that the first iteration of the loop would produce $session=1 and $item=50?

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: yes using ajax to reoder list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, `$_POST['session'][$i]` and `$value` would be the same thing, which contains `array(0 => 50, 1 => 60)` for the first iteration.

In the first iteration `$session` is not defined yet, so you cannot access `$session[$i]`.

To get what you want to achieve:

```
foreach ($_POST['session'] as $i => $value) {
    $session = $i;  //1
    $item = $value[0]; //50, and $value[1] is 60
}
```

To understand more about what the contents of a variable is, you can print its content using `print_r($value)` for example, so you will know what its content and structure look like.

***UPDATE***

To iterate all the values for each session:

```
foreach ($_POST['session'] as $session => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $item) {
        //do whatever you want here with the $session and $item
        //over all the iterations, here we will have:
        //iteration#1   $session=1, $item=50
        //iteration#2   $session=1, $item=60
        //iteration#3   $session=2, $item=70
        //iteration#4   $session=3, $item=80
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense - but how do I iterate through the $value array within the loop so I can access $value[1] for example, where the number of items is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print all the values in the variable, you should use nested loop here.

```
foreach ($_POST['session'] as $i => $value) {  /* Accessing session[1], session[2] ... */
    foreach ($value as $val) {  /* session[1][0], session[1][1] ..... */
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
50&60&70&80
```

Comment: thanks yes I ultimately want to use the values in a query - I have updated the question to show this